# Apache axis2 version for Tomcat 7.0.82

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

My current Tomcat version is 7.0.77 and axis2 version 1.4.1.

I need to upgrade Tomcat version to 7.0.82 and my existing Axis2 (version: 1.4.1) does not start up with it.
Should I upgrade Axis2 version also with Tomcat 7.0.82

Comment: I am not sure if this will be much of a help. But in general the versions of all of the software that you mention are very old. Tomcat 7 was released in 2014, and I think the most recent version of Axis2 was released sometime in 2016. A couple questions. What versions of these tools are you upgrading from? And must you stay with these tools and older versions of them? Could you go to a newer Tomcat and a more modern web services framework?

Comment: My current versions are: tomcat:7.0.77  axis2: 1.4.1. I need to upgrade Tomcat version to 7.0.82. this is my workplace requirement and I need to stick to the Tomcat 7.0.82 version :) . So my question is, with Tomcat 7.0.82, axis2 (1.4.1) does not work properly. Should I upgrade axis2 version, if so which version.